# lm produces different coefficients in r

Tags: r, lm, poly

```
attach(mtcars)

poly_model <- lm(mpg ~ poly(hp,degree=1), data = mtcars)
summary(poly_model)
lin_model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
summary(lin_model)

x <- with(mtcars, seq(min(hp), max(hp), length.out=2000))
y1 <- predict(poly_model, newdata = data.frame(hp = x))
y2 <- predict(lin_model, newdata = data.frame(hp = x))

plot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
lines(x, y1, col = "red")
lines(x, y2, col = "blue")
```

poly_model and lin_model produce different coefficients.

```
poly_model
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           20.0906     0.6829  29.420  < 2e-16 ***
poly(hp, degree = 1) -26.0456     3.8630  -6.742 1.79e-07 ***

lin_model
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 30.09886    1.63392  18.421  < 2e-16 ***
hp          -0.06823    0.01012  -6.742 1.79e-07 ***
```

By inspection of the plot, it appears the lin_model coefficients are correct. Why does poly_model appear to produce different coefficients? The plots overlap and R2 is the same for both.

Comment: Try with `raw = TRUE` `unname(coef(summary(poly_model))[, "Estimate"])#
[1] 30.09886054 -0.06822828`

Comment: I am not following. Those are the lin_model coefficients, which appear to be correct. Where should I insert "raw = TRUE"?

Comment: `poly_model <- lm(mpg ~ poly(hp,degree=1, raw = TRUE), data = mtcars)`

Comment: Thanks!! That worked great.